# PHP drops session-cookie only if inactivity period is between 24 minutes and 55 minutes

Tags: php, session-cookies

**Technology stack:** Nginx > Apache > PHP > BitrixCMS.

**Issue:** If inactivity period is between 24 minutes and 55 minutes then PHP will drop session by sending new PHPSESSID cookie in response. If inactivity period is greater than 55 minutes then PHP will accept session by responding without new PHPSESSID cookie and complete operation while processing further requests with 60 minutes old PHPSESSID .

**OK Example:** "set up" request and "complete" request with 30 minutes of inactivity. Server drops session by sending new PHPSESSID in response header

```
[REQUEST]
Request URL: https://example.com/set-up/
Request Method: POST
...
Cookie: PHPSESSID=21hg579oq7n28h0la7061dhsh5; ...
...
[RESPONSE]
...
Date: Tue, 08 Jun 2021 13:34:39 GMT
...
```

```
[REQUEST]
Request URL: https://example.com/complete/
Request Method: POST
...
Cookie: PHPSESSID=21hg579oq7n28h0la7061dhsh5; ...
...
[RESPONSE]
...
Date: Tue, 08 Jun 2021 14:03:44 GMT
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=97d4106db4d1095ad053d96f74366739; path=/ ...
...
```

**NOK Example:** "set up" request and "complete" request with 60 minutes of inactivity. Server doesn't drop session (there is no set-cookie header) and processes all requests with 60 minutes old PHPSESSID.

```
[REQUEST]
Request URL: https://example.com/set-up/
Request Method: POST
...
Cookie: PHPSESSID=qkfhm4udb1sd9p1bprj5o90c3i; ...
...
[RESPONSE]
...
Date: Wed, 09 Jun 2021 06:39:39 GMT
...
```

```
[REQUEST]
Request URL: https://example.com/complete/
Request Method: POST
...
Cookie: PHPSESSID=qkfhm4udb1sd9p1bprj5o90c3i; ...
...
[RESPONSE]
...
Date: Wed, 09 Jun 2021 07:39:15 GMT
...
```

**Question:** I do understand that most likely it is mistake in PHP code, check in progress. Are there any suggestions about this situation? Any configs that can make impact here?

Comment: Rather unlikely, that the general session configuration has something to do with this. The minimum amount of time after which an inactive session can be cleaned up by the garbage collector is 24 minutes by default - but that would not explain why it works again on the other side of > 55 min. That some lifetime check _inside_ the script is responsible for this, is therefor more likely IMHO.